# setOnSeekbarChangeListener() is not working for me

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I cant get `SetOnSeekBarChangeListener` to work for some weird reason.

Whenever i use the code i pasted below i get:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnSeekBarChangeListener'

I have also tried using OnSeekBarChangeListener without the set in front of it.

Anybody that is able to help me fix this?

```
SeekBar volumeBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        
        
});
```

Comment: Try building the project.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to import this

```
    import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;


    volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Imported this but it says unused import statement?

Answer (score 0):

Click on *Build*

[image]

And then click on *Clean Project*

[image]

And make sure you are using the whole `Listener`.

```
 volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Clean Project didn't change anything for me.
I pasted your code in my program but didn't work either.
setOnSeekBarChangeListener still cant resolve symbol.
And the seekBar in the override parts also cant be resolved.

Comment: Then try to create a new project and check weather it's working there.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code u have written,under pre-built "Oncreate" method...it will work now fine.

[Here is the your modified code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Hk8.png)